# Multiple target GitLab CI pipeline - cancellation of branch pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am slowly learning the rules configuration for gitlab-ci but I need help sorting one thing that doesn't seems to work; namely the non cancellation of branch deployment when a merge request deployment is being triggered.

This is a web stack pipeline using AWS CDK and React apps and following somewhat of a gitflow (unique `main` branch and multiple long lived `feature` branches)

I do not have access to the underlying runners as those are set up internally.

I have 3-4 target environment to which I need to deploy in a very classic way, those are sequentially triggered (DV -> ST/AT -> PR). All targets are to build and deploy to AWS accounts (one per environment). I can do that without any issue using the stage order and be very verbose:

```yaml
stages:
  ...
  - build-dev
  - test-dev
  - deploy-dev
  - build-st
  - test-st
  - deploy-st
  - build-prod
  - deploy-prod
```

However I cannot have a clean deployment of branch(es) and merge request without having a double deployment if I trigger a merge request before the branch pipeline is complete. I though naively that I would need to set rules and conditions for both the branch pipeline and the merge request pipeline while setting them up in the correct order of execution:

```yaml
stages:
  - build-branch
  - test-branch
  - deploy-branch
  - build-merge-request
  - test-merge-request
  - clean-merge-request
  ...
```

I have currently the workflow configured as such

```yaml
workflow:
  auto_cancel:
    on_new_commit: interruptible

  # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

And additionally I have set some hidden job to try and modify the jobs accordingly:

```yaml
.conditions:
  branch:
    variables:
      ENVIRONMENT: $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    rules:
      # - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH &&  $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"
        when: always
  merge_request:
    variables:
      ENVIRONMENT: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
    rules:
      - if: $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
        when: always
  default:
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  dev:
    variables:
      ENVIRONMENT: dev
    rules:
      - !reference [.conditions, default, rules]
  prod:
    variables:
      ENVIRONMENT: prod
    rules:
      - !reference [.conditions, default, rules]
```

It seems to do the following:

- initial push for the branch triggers a branch deployment
- subsequent push to the branch triggers also a branch deployment
- any push while a deployment is running will cancel the current pipeline and trigger a new one
- any merge request event will trigger a deployment
- any running branch deployment will not be cancelled by a new merge request deployment
- DV, ST/AT, PR deployment are running sequentially as expected

Comment: I am aware of this issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17046 "Skip job if already run on same code" which at the time of writing is open (and 7yo)